# How to fix this issue "ERROR: Failed building wheel for insightface"

Tags: python, python-extensions

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for insightface
Failed to build insightface
ERROR: Could not build wheels for insightface, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I have tried everything like updating and etc

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Without error log I can just guess, but under Windows, you may need to install the Microsoft C++ Build Tools (`error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`).

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this issue on my Ubuntu 22, and it was resolved by using `sudo apt-get install build-essential`. I hope this is helpful for everyone.

Comment: It works on my Ubuntu 20. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on my desktop where I was building a project on Windows 11.

You need to install Microsoft build tools from this link (or latest)
https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_BuildTools.exe

Select: **Workloads** → **Desktop development with C++**

Individual Components must be checked:

- **Windows SDK**
- **C++ x64/x86 build tools**

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's was we need. Thanks for share.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, LNK2001 errors and an exit code of 2011 that cause the wheel build to fail are not uncommon. Unfortunately, the solution is not easy to find without a deeper understanding of Python and its build behavior in Windows.

Insightface uses setuptools, Cython, and the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler to perform it's build. **How you set up the build environment varies depending on which version of Python you are using.** Refer to the Python [WindowsCompilers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers) wiki topic for instructions appropriate to your particular Python version.

After that, make sure that you use pip to update or install setuptools and Cython.

In my case I have:

> Python 3.11.8 (tags/v3.11.8:db85d51, Feb  6 2024, 22:03:32) [MSC
> v.1937 64 bit (AMD64)]

Neither the standard Windows Command Prompt nor the Developer Command Prompt for VS2022 were sufficient to get a successful build even after following the instructions in the wiki article. It wasn't until I used the **x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022** that I was able to get a successful build and install of insightface in Windows.