# Is it possible to force pip to use MingwW64-x86_64-gcc/g++ instead of the Visual Studio BuildTools Package?

Tags: visual-studio, pip, msys2, build-tools

Adding on to an earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76739044/how-to-fix-this-issue-error-failed-building-wheel-for-insightface) asked about building wheels for [Insightface](https://github.com/deepinsight/insightface) - (*this solved my issue for now*), I'd like to know whether it's possible to change the building tools `pip` defaults to, for example from Microsoft.Visual.Studio.BuildTools2022 to MingwW64-x86_64-gcc/g++(*I really dislike Visual Studio and don't want to install it*) installed using MSYS2.

So, I tried declaring(*explicitly*) the `C` and `CXX` environment variables to point to the binaries in MSYS2's default install location in `sysdm.cpl`, obviously that didn't work. Also, I tried installing `gcc/g++` and `clang` using my trusty package managers to see which one would work. I've fixed the issue but I'd like to know whether there's a workaround to installing Visual Studio whatever in my system.